# Saned not providing scanner over netowrk

Tags: linux, networking, scanner

Just upgraded my file server to Mageia 7. It seemed to go pretty well, but even with good backups, I'm not able to get some stuff back. For example, my flatbed scanner is no longer working over the network. The scanner (details below) is connected to the server via USB and has been working just fine for years. It still works on the server locally, but I can no longer get my Mageia 7 desktop to connect to it. Again, it all worked just fine prior to the upgrade. I don't see this as network trouble. I may be wrong.

Here are some details.

Linux shuttle 5.4.2-desktop-1.mga7 #1 SMP Thu Dec 5 17:40:00 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

(from "scanimage -L" on the server) device `genesys:libusb:002:002' is a Canon LiDE 110 flatbed scanner

scanimage (sane-backends) 1.0.27; backend version 1.0.28

Scanner works locally on server (192.168.1.105), but does not work from a desktop on the LAN (192.168.1.106). I removed (x)sane from the server to test without it. It made no difference - the desktop still can't find the scanner.

I am unable to connect to port 6566 on the server via telnet. Connection closes immediately:

```
# telnet shuttle 6566
Trying 192.168.1.105...
Connected to shuttle.
Escape character is '^]'.
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

scanimage -L on the desktop fails to see the scanner

saned.socket is running:

```
# systemctl status saned.socket
● saned.socket - saned incoming socket
Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/saned.socket; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: active (listening) since Sun 2019-12-15 20:41:33 MST; 13h ago
Listen: [::]:6566 (Stream)
Accepted: 36; Connected: 0;
Memory: 128.0K
CGroup: /system.slice/saned.socket

Dec 15 20:41:33 shuttle systemd[1]: Listening on saned incoming socket
```

saned.socket shows open and listening per other tools as well:

```
nmap -sV shuttle -p 6566
Starting Nmap 7.70 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2019-12-16 10:34 MST
Nmap scan report for shuttle (192.168.1.105)
Host is up (0.00015s latency).

PORT STATE SERVICE VERSION
6566/tcp open tcpwrapped
```

## netstat -l |grep sane-port

tcp6 0 0 [::]:sane-port [::]:*

my user is in the server's "scanner" group
saned is in "lp" group
Firewalls are down

/etc/saned/net.conf:

```
## saned hosts
::1
localhost
192.168.1.106
192.168.1.105
```

/etc/hosts.allow is set for ALL:AL

The only thing I notice that seems questionable is an undefined symbol that shows up in the journalctl readout from the server when I try to connect to the scanner from the desktop:

```
Dec 16 15:49:00 shuttle saned[24912]: /usr/sbin/saned: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/saned: undefined symbol: sanei_w_init
Dec 16 15:49:00 shuttle systemd[1]: saned@71-192.168.1.105:6566-192.168.1.106:36174.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 16 15:49:00 shuttle systemd[1]: saned@71-192.168.1.105:6566-192.168.1.106:36174.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I initially asked this question at linuxquestions.org and we were unable to resolve the issue. One exchange did reveal a potential issue in saned.socket as the command "scanimage -L" was issued from the desktop machine - an undefined symbol, "sanei_w_init":

```
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle systemd[1]: Started Scanner Service (192.168.1.106:37670).
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle saned[26138]: /usr/sbin/saned: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/saned: undefined symbol: sanei_w_init
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle systemd[1]: saned@85-192.168.1.105:6566-192.168.1.106:37670.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle systemd[1]: saned@85-192.168.1.105:6566-192.168.1.106:37670.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle systemd[1]: Started Scanner Service (192.168.1.106:37672).
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle saned[26141]: /usr/sbin/saned: symbol lookup error: /usr/sbin/saned: undefined symbol: sanei_w_init
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle systemd[1]: saned@86-192.168.1.105:6566-192.168.1.106:37672.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=127/n/a
Dec 16 18:00:36 shuttle systemd[1]: saned@86-192.168.1.105:6566-192.168.1.106:37672.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

There is no real information about what that symbol means or ramifications for that undefined symbol.

I posted essentially the same information above to the Mageia forum last night and 14 hours later there are more than 15 views and no responses to that message.

I can't think of anything else to check. Does anybody here have any suggestions?

Thanks for the time and attention.

Mark

Edit: I've seen a report of issues caused by having both saned and xsane installed on the server. I have uninstalled xsane on the server and it made no difference.